# Prove/disprove that irrational - irrational is always irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

could you help me?
I am trying to prove / disprove that the subtraction of two irrational numbers is irrational

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ i want to prove that exists some $i\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ that satisfies $$a-b=i$$
By contradiction suppose that $a-b=r$ with $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, then
$$a=r+b$$
but $r+b$  is a irrational (i proved it before)
¡¡BUT HERE THERE WAS NO CONTRADICTION!!

In the other hand suppose $ a-b = i $, then
$$ a = b + i $$ This is where I have a problem, I know that the sum of a rational number and an irrational number can be rational or irrational. So what can I do?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: $\sqrt2-\sqrt2=0$

Comment: This is false. For example $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}=0$ which is rational.

Comment: And $i^2=-1$ and not $i=a-b$ for real numbers :)

Comment: Any example you have of, say, "rational+irrational =irrational" immediately gives you an example of "irrational-irrational=rational".

Comment: +1 to this question, which I consider very legitimate, where the OP has shown work.  I was surprised to find this question in the close queue.  The only reason that I am reacting with a comment rather than an answer is that a thorough answer to this question requires a knowledge of **Field Theory**, which I don't have.  If $(a - b) = r = (p/q)$, with integers $p,q : q\neq 0$ then $q(a-b) = p$.  As (in effect) others have indicated, this is obviously possible if $(a-b)= 0.$  Studying this question, when $(a-b) \neq 0$ requires that you study Field Theory.

Comment: @user2661923 oh wow, and I'm only in the first semester of college, anyway thanks for your comment :D